# If $2^\mu$ and $2^\lambda$ are isomorphic as boolean algebras, is it true that $\mu = \lambda$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

The content of this question is:

> Is what I am going to say correct?

It is well known that given two cardinals $\lambda < \mu$ it might be the case that $2^{\lambda} = 2^{\mu}$. Even stronger, the Easton theorem says that it is consistent with ZFC to force some of these equalities.

This means that there might be a bijection between the set $2^\lambda$ and the set $2^\mu$. On the other hand I claim that this correspondence cannot be a morphism of boolean algebras. In fact, the following seems to hold.

**Lemma** Let If $2^\mu$ and $2^\lambda$ are isomorphic as boolean algebras then $\mu = \lambda$.

By boolean algebra morphism I mean a function that preserve sups and inf.

The proof is very simple. Such a map $\phi$ would preserve completely join-irreducible elements. In a boolean algebra those correspond to the atoms of the boolean algebra. Thus $\phi$ restrict to a bijection of the atoms, which is the thesis.

Comment: Maybe a clearer title is in order? You have 150 characters at your disposal. Surely you can put something like the formulation of the Lemma in there...

Comment: @Asaf, any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Just as a remark, I am pretty sure this is a duplicate. But a quick search wasn't productive, and I don't have time to dig into this right now...

Comment: Thanks for the better title.

Comment: I just copied your lemma's formulation... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.  More strongly, in fact, you can say that if $\lambda<\mu$, then there is no injective homomorphism of Boolean algebras $2^\mu\to 2^\lambda$, since such a homomorphism would have to send the atoms of $2^\mu$ to a collection of $\mu$ pairwise disjoint nonzero elements of $2^\lambda$, which is not possible if $\lambda<\mu$.

Another strengthening of your statement is that the category of Boolean algebras of the form $2^X$, with *complete* (i.e., preserving infinite joins) Boolean homomorphisms as morphisms, is equivalent to the opposite category of sets.  That is, any complete homomorphism $2^X\to 2^Y$ must be the map induced by a unique map $Y\to X$.  The proof is straightforward: just look at where each atom of $2^X$ gets sent, and use the fact that every element of $2^X$ is a join of atoms.  It follows that if $2^X$ and $2^Y$ are isomorphic in this category (i.e., isomorphic as Boolean algebras, since any isomorphism of Boolean algebras is complete), then $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic as sets.

Comment: Of course I knew the second part of the answer, but I never realized its deep meaning before the question.

Comment: Does this imply that the ultrafilter functor is fully faithful as well?

Comment: @Cayley-Hamilton: What, precisely, do you mean by the ultrafilter functor?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that, for the endofunctor of set assigning a set to its ultrafilters, that if λ < μ implies U λ< U μ?

Comment: @Cayley-Hamilton: No, if $\lambda$ is infinite then there are $2^{2^{\lambda}}$ ultrafilters on $\lambda$, so if $\lambda<\mu$ but $2^{\lambda}=2^\mu$ then there are the same number of ultrafilters on $\lambda$ and $\mu$.